# How to run two modules at the same time in IDLE

Tags: python, sockets, python-idle

I am working on a super simple socket program and I have code for the client and code for the server. How do I run both these .py files at the same time to see if they work ?

Comment: Use two terminal windows.

Comment: The following stackflow answer link gives instructions on how to simultaneously start two or more IDLE instances to run python server and client or other scripts simultaneously on a Macintosh using OSX (and still also working for later versions of OSX and python) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52372490/open-multiple-idle-shells-in-python-3-6-mac-osx-10-12

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can run multiple instances of IDLE/Python shell at the same time. So open IDLE and run the server code and then open up IDLE again, which will start a separate instance and then run your client code.

Comment: Now flag it answered so people know!

Comment: ah! got it. I didn't know there was a waiting period.

Answer (score 0):

For newbies like myself: do not open the client script/file from the first opened IDLE Shell, with the server script already running in the Editor window, but open another IDLE Shell window, in which you open/run this client script.