# Open multiple IDLE shells in python 3.6 Mac OSX 10.12

Tags: python, macos, terminal, python-idle

I want to run two or more different python scripts simultaneously in IDLE. I want to use IDLE directly, not terminal. I want to use all of them with Python 3.6. I'm on Mac 10.12. Can I do this?

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/566676/how-to-open-multiple-python-shells-via-idle-on-mac?rq=1) opens a Python 2.7 IDLE window. I don't understand [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15329649/how-to-run-two-modules-at-the-same-time-in-idle).

If I CAN'T do this, can I run multiple python scripts from the terminal simultaneously?

Comment: What makes you think you *can't* run multiple scripts from the command line simultaneously?

Comment: This also depends on how you installed Python 3. The command `idle3` opens the version 3 IDLE for me and I seem to be running several of them without any issue. But not running IDLE seems like a much more fruitful and normal thing to do.

Comment: In one terminal, run `python3 ./script1.py`. In another terminal, run `python3 ./script2.py`. Or if the first one doesn't require any user interaction, you can run it in the background with `python3 ./script1.py &` and run the second one in the same terminal

Comment: Some programs take measures to ensure that only one instance of the program is running.  Python and IDLE do not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. From a terminal window type `idle3 &`. This will bring up the idle3 window and leaving the terminal window still functional. Now type `idle3 &` again and you'll get another idle3 window. You can do this more times if needed.

An alternative method is to open an iTerm or Terminal window and under the shell menu, you can open a new tab. Do this however many times you wish. Now in each tab type idle3. You can open as many idle3 windows as you wish.